# LESS not working in IE11 - Why?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, web, less

I have the following example:

```
<style type="text/less">
@bg: black;
@fg: white;
body {
 background-color: @bg;
 color: @fg;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"
  src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.7.3/less.js">
</script>
<title> test </title>
</head>

<body>
test

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  alert("test");
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

It shows a JavaScript alert and white text on black ground in Firefox, Chrome and Opera. For some reason, it does not work in IE11: The alert is being shown, but the LESS parsing does not happen. I made the IE11 Developer Tools break on all exceptions, but nothing seems to go wrong.

The alert is here because I was worried that Internet Explorer might not be executing scripts at all, but this is clearly not the case.

Btw, I also tried this with the earlier version

```
https://raw.github.com/cloudhead/less.js/master/dist/less-1.3.3.min.js
```

instead of the one from `cdnjs.cloudflare.com`, no luck either.

As far as I know, LESS should be supported on IE11. I would be very grateful if anyone had any idea why it is not working.

**Edit** It seems like this may be a problem with my internet explorer configuration. I am on a Windows 2008 R2 machine with all my Internet Explorer settings at default.

Comment: Apart from what morkro has already posted, I could not find any other issues too. But have a look at this [**thread**](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?1188801-CSS-not-working-at-all-in-IE11!) and see if anything mentioned there helps you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place your LESS code *after* the `<script>`tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"
  src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.7.3/less.js">
</script>
<style type="text/less">
@bg: black;
@fg: white;
body {
 background-color: @bg;
 color: @fg;
}
</style>
<title> test </title>
```

If you place it before you include `less.js` the browser doesn't know what to do with that piece of code. That is why it doesn't get parsed.

Another approach: remove `language="JavaScript"` on all `<script>` tags as the attribute has been deprecated.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I thought of that already and tried both orders. Neither works =(.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. Removed both of them and tried both arrangements of script and style. The alert window pops up, but no black background.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8vvf/) works for me even with IE9. Do you have a link to your problem or can you provide a jsFiddle of your problem?

Comment: Alright. That does not even *load* in my IE11 unless I add jsfiddle.net to my "trusted sites". After that, it neither shows the alert popup nor changes the colors. I have the distinct feeling that this has to do with my internet explorer configuration, but I really don't know what might be causing it.

Comment: PS: +1 for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Gern! Let us know when your problem is fixed _(or if we can help more out)_, so that I can edit my answer for other users who might have the same trouble.

Comment: @morko: Years later, everything works perfectly fine on Windows 10 / edge. It was something with the security configuration in Windows 2008 I suspect, but I may never find out what exactly it was. I am accepting your answer to close this question.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Interesting :) Thanks for the follow up!